# Servlet 3.0 Async-supported does not work

Tags: servlets, asynchronous, servlet-filters

Here is my web.xml

```
    <filter>
    <filter-name>pollingTest</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        webapp.controller.core.servlet.PollingService
            </filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>pollingTest</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/poll</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ASYNC</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Here is the class:

```
public class PollingService implements Filter {
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

@Override
public void destroy() {
    logger.info("Destroy");
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    logger.info("Running");
    req.startAsync(req, res);
    this.doFilter(req, res, chain);
    return;
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {

    logger.info("Init=");
}
```

}

I run it on glassfish and also on tomcat 7, got exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Request is within the scope of a filter or servlet that does not support asynchronous operations
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.startAsync(Request.java:3657)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.startAsync(Request.java:3633)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.startAsync(RequestFacade.java:1053)
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.startAsync(ServletRequestWrapper.java:450)
```

Who can help me on this? thanks a lot.

Comment: show the whole web.xml (at least the `<web-app>` tag definition with the namespaces)

Answer (score 52):

Because your servlet and any other filter in chain must have `<async-supported>true</async-supported>` in web.xml.

Comment: how to do this with annotation?

Comment: @WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/*", asyncSupported = true)

Comment: Netbeans 8.2 / Tomcat 8.0.27: I also had to disable HTTP monitor (Services -> Servers -> Right click on Apache Tomcat -> Properties -> uncheck Enable HTTP monitor). It looks like it is a [bug](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=236064).

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem, but in my case, it was not enough. If you use tags Context and Valve (in tomcat7 - service.xml), you must add parameter asyncSupported="true" in tag value. Then it had worked.

```
<Context docBase="aaa" path="/aaa" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:aaa"><Valve className="cz.tomcatUtil.ForceUserValve" user="DZC0GRP" asyncSupported="true"/></Context>
```

Answer (score 4):

You're calling recursively `this.doFilter(req, res, chain);`.

If you want continue the chain, you must invoke `chain.doFilter(httpRequest, httpResponse);` instead of `this.doFilter(req, res, chain);`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Annotation for Mapping Asynchronous Servlet like this

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/yourServlet"}, **asyncSupported=true**)

public class YourServlet extends HttpServlet { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Peter Karabinovich, you answer isn't true. From Servlet 3.0 spec:

> **2.3.3.3 Asynchronous processing**
>   
> ...
>   Dispatching from a servlet that has asyncSupported=true to one where
>   asyncSupported is set to false is **allowed**. In this case, the response will be
>   committed when the service method of the servlet that does not support async is
>   exited...

Comment: per Servlet 4.0 specification: "..It is illegal to call startAsync if the request is within the scope of a servlet or filter that does not support asynchronous operations..."

Answer (score 0):

I know this an old post but I would like to share my solution. It took me 1 week to find out the cause because I had tried almost tried every possible solution.

For me the servlet url-pattern was not correct.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/pattern/</url-pattern> <---
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Hope it will be of some use.